# Change the hamburger icon in Xamarin.Forms for Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, icons

How can I change the hamburger icon for in Xamarin.Forms for Android?

I use the style : "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar". And I need to use a MasterDetailPage.

But ... I would like to change the hamburger icon (Top left) or in the worst case, change the color of this icon (black -> white).

Thank you in advance !

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69113/how-can-i-change-the-hamburger-icon-for-another-one-in-xamarin-forms-for-android